# Need lightweight browser that will truly open each tab I give it

Tags: windows-7, web-browser

Chrome and Opera only open a tab when it's truly needed.  I need a browser that will open 25 tabs, not on a contingency basis, but really open them.

I've tried Firefox and Pale Moon.  They do load all the tabs, BUT they get all tied into knots when I give them 25 tabs.

I'm not going to use the browser for general research, only to open specific websites that don't have advertising, etc.  But I really do need to open all 25 tabs at once.  I'm open to using an older version of a browser -- this project has a limited time scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "get all tied in knots"?  Do you need it to be fast to *open* the tabs, or fast once the tabs are already open?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - I only need it to be reasonably fast.  It's been using so much memory that sometimes my tabs don't load at all. They pull from a large database, using a lot of memory resources. I've been seeing a number above 2 million in the task manager in the memory column. When I put in a different parameter the browser gets so befuddled I have to restart the browser, but I would prefer not to have to do that every time I change the parameter. (For normal web browsing I plan to continue to use opera.)

Comment: Hmmm... do the pages have any graphics, or are they text only?  I ask because PortableApps has the Lynx and Linx text-based browsers.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - I found http://invisible-island.net/lynx/#installers but am not sure what to download there.  I downloaded Lynx from Portable Apps but it didn't want to run.  Couldn't find Linx.

Comment: Try downloading the PortableApps Platform from https://portableapps.com/download - Then, using its menus, download Lynx or Linx.  They are both in listed in the *Internet* section once the Platform is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, what was bothering me about Opera was that it was delaying loading pages.  There is a setting for that!  I turned it off, and then was able to use Opera for my task.  Memory and CPU are still spiking but are staying manageable.